# Unknown error occurred while loading settings firebase setup. Firebase console failure

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-console

On the firebase console, currently I cannot even save settings for my newly created project. This made me to delete a project yesterday and after creating a new one, the same errors still pops up on the screen stating `unknown error occurred while loading settings. Please refresh the page` , `unknown error occurred while loading users` and `unknown error occurred`. I **cannot** even **save settings** or even turn on **authentication providers**. 
I have refreshed the page severally. I have even closed browser and opened again.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think its better that you contact Firebase support for this issue.

Comment: I have already done. It's very close to a service outage issue

Comment: I just toggled a few authentication providers on my projects and got no errors. Check your JavaScript console for errors that seem related, and disable all browser extensions. Beyond that, as André said, this is better handled through Firebase support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not something many developers can help with. It is a better fit for Firebase support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I access it in incognito mode